# How to combine 2 or more objects in a list based on certain fields of those objects

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm sorry if the title sounds vague.

I have an object -

```
    public class AccountInfo {
        private String accountId;
        private Double vat;
        private Double totalFee;
        private Date invoiceDate;
    }
```

and there is a list of these objects-

```
List<AccountInfo> AccountInfoLst;
```

I want to manipulate this list by combining objects with the same **accountId** by adding up the **vat** and **totalFee** fields, provided they have the same **invoiceDate** as well.

If two objects have the same **accountId** but different **invoiceDate**, they shouldn't be combined.

Comment: I think you should attempt some code.  This is a simple stream/loop.

Comment: Sidenote: You forgot to provide a type for the `invoiceDate` (not that it's too important, but just for completeness).

Comment: Unrelated but are you sure you should be using `Double` instead of `double`?

Comment: @markspace I have tried quite a few different things but I am unable to wrap my head around it.

Comment: @Nexevis Double is what I have to use here.

Comment: And you shouldn't use `Date`, as it is obsolete. Use classes from the `java.time` package. In your case probably `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it utilizing **Streams** one of the possible ways will be to `collect` the data into the `Map`, using as a key an object that combines `accountId` and `invoiceDate`.

All accounts **mapped to the same key** will be **merged**.

Accounts that **differ** in `accountId` or `invoiceDate` will remain intact.

Another option will be to create a nested map. In which `accountId` will be used as a key, a value will be a map which will use in turn `invoiceDate` as a key and a value will be an `AccountInfo`.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<AccountInfo> result = List.of(
                    new AccountInfo("123", 80., 180., LocalDate.now()),
                    new AccountInfo("123", 120., 590., LocalDate.now()),
                    new AccountInfo("123", 30., 120., LocalDate.now().minusDays(3))
                )
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        AccountWrapper::new,
                        UnaryOperator.identity(),
                        (acc1, acc2) -> new AccountInfo(
                                acc1.getAccountId(),
                                acc1.getVat() + acc2.getVat(),
                                acc1.getTotalFee() + acc2.getTotalFee(),
                                acc1.getInvoiceDate())
                ))
                .values().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        result.forEach(System.out::println);
    }



    public record AccountWrapper(String accountId, LocalDate invoiceDate) {
        public AccountWrapper(AccountInfo info) {
            this(info.getAccountId(), info.getInvoiceDate());
        }
    }
```

If you are using **Java 15 or earlier** AccountWrapper could be implemented as a **regular class**:

```
    public class AccountWrapper {
        private final String accountId;
        private final LocalDate invoiceDate;

        public AccountWrapper(AccountInfo info) {
            this.accountId = info.getAccountId();
            this.invoiceDate = info.getInvoiceDate();
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(accountId, invoiceDate);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            AccountWrapper other = (AccountWrapper) o;
            return accountId.equals(other.accountId) && invoiceDate.equals(other.invoiceDate);
        }
    }
```

Version with a **nested map**, no auxiliary objects are needed

```
        List<AccountInfo> result = List.of(
                        new AccountInfo("123", 80., 180., LocalDate.now()),
                        new AccountInfo("123", 120., 590., LocalDate.now()),
                        new AccountInfo("123", 30., 120., LocalDate.now().minusDays(3))
                )
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        AccountInfo::getAccountId,
                        Collectors.toMap(
                                AccountInfo::getInvoiceDate,
                                UnaryOperator.identity(),
                                (acc1, acc2) -> new AccountInfo(
                                    acc1.getAccountId(),
                                    acc1.getVat() + acc2.getVat(),
                                    acc1.getTotalFee() + acc2.getTotalFee(),
                                    acc1.getInvoiceDate())
                        )))
                .values().stream()
                .flatMap(map -> map.values().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

**output**

```
AccountInfo{accountId='123', vat=200.0, totalFee=770.0, invoiceDate=2022-02-09}
AccountInfo{accountId='123', vat=30.0, totalFee=120.0, invoiceDate=2022-02-06}
```

Comment: Can we do it without the constructor?

Comment: @AdityaThakur you mean without a `record AccountWrapper` (it's just an immutable class with a simplified declaration) ? Yes, that's doable, you can skip the record, if you can define `equals()` and `hashCode()` directly in the `AccountInfo` based on `accountId` and  `invoiceDate`.

Comment: [Record AccountWrapper](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html) saves you from needing to these changes if `AccountWrapper` is a part of the legacy system and you have no control over it.

Comment: I have to use java 8 so Record won't be available for me. Can I group the make a nested map by by grouping by accountId and then by invoice date and then combine the lists?

Comment: @AdityaThakur I've updated the code in my answer. Just substitute the record with a `regular class`.

Comment: @AdityaThakur I've also added a version with a nested map in which auxiliary class is `not` needed. It works fine.

Comment: Thanks, I understood the last one and it worked for me. I accepted it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the list which are duplicate combine them to one AccountInfo and remove all the duplicates.

Since Date is deprecated we have used java.time.LocalDate.

### Code:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

class AccountInfo {
    private String accountId;

    private Double vat;
    private Double totalFee;
    private LocalDate invoiceDate;

    public Double getVat() {
        return vat;
    }

    public void setVat(Double vat) {
        this.vat = vat;
    }

    public Double getTotalFee() {
        return totalFee;
    }

    public void setTotalFee(Double totalFee) {
        this.totalFee = totalFee;
    }

    public LocalDate getInvoiceDate() {
        return invoiceDate;
    }

    public void setInvoiceDate(LocalDate invoiceDate) {
        this.invoiceDate = invoiceDate;
    }

    public AccountInfo(String accountId, Double vat, Double totalFee, LocalDate invoiceDate) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
        this.vat = vat;
        this.totalFee = totalFee;
        this.invoiceDate = invoiceDate;
    }

    public String getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

    public void setAccountId(String accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return accountId + " " + vat + " " + totalFee + " " + invoiceDate;
    }

    public boolean areEquals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        AccountInfo that = (AccountInfo) o;
        var thatInvoiceDate = that.getInvoiceDate();
        var thisInvoiceDate = getInvoiceDate();
        return that.getAccountId().equals(getAccountId()) && thatInvoiceDate.isEqual(thisInvoiceDate);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(accountId, vat, totalFee, invoiceDate);
    }
}

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String... $) {
        var out = System.out;
        
        List<AccountInfo> accounts = Stream.of(new AccountInfo("A", 20.2, 200.4, LocalDate.of(2022, 11, 3))
                , new AccountInfo("A", 20.2, 200.4, LocalDate.of(2022, 11, 3)),
                new AccountInfo("B", 20.2, 200.4, LocalDate.of(2023, 11, 2)),
                new AccountInfo("B", 20.2, 200.4, LocalDate.of(2023, 11, 2))).collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        //Iterating over all the accounts
        for (int i = 0; i < accounts.size(); i++) {
            var account = accounts.get(i);
            ArrayList<AccountInfo> duplicates = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = i + 1; j < accounts.size(); j++) {
                var acc = accounts.get(j);
                if (acc.areEquals(account))
                    duplicates.add(acc);
            }
//            out.println(i + " " + indices);
            //Merging all duplicates to account
            for (AccountInfo acc : duplicates) {
                account.setTotalFee(acc.getTotalFee() + account.getTotalFee());
                account.setVat(acc.getVat() + account.getVat());
            }
            //Removing all duplicates
            accounts.removeAll(duplicates);
        }
        //printing accounts after removal of duplicates
        out.println(accounts);
    }
}
```

### Output:

```
[A 40.4 400.8 2022-11-03, B 40.4 400.8 2023-11-02]
```